# SSRS Tablix and Chart Filtering

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-tablix

I have a chart and matrix that shows records for  a given date range. User wants to see the records for indidual months.If the user selects date range from January to April then the results would be 4 charts and 4 tablix based on month instead of single chart and single tablix that shows for all months. Could anyone please help me on how to do that. TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a list
2. Insert your existing Tablix/Matrix into the body of the list
3. Right click the Row header (grey box) of the List and on the General tab set the Group expression to group on the Month value, i.e.

   ```
   =Month(Fields!myDate.Value)
   ```
4. Right click the Row header (grey box) of the List and on the Filters tab set two expressions.

   ```
   Expression           Operator Value
   -------------------- -------- --------------------------
   =Fields!myDate.Value >=       =Parameters!StartDate.Value
   =Fields!myDate.Value <=       =Parameters!EndDate.Value
   ```

This approach will then take an output that looks like this (for all months)

[image]

When applied, and the parameters set so that `StartDate = 01/Jan/2015` and `EndDate = 28/Feb/2015`, will look like this

[image]

Note how the data for each month appears separately.

Let me know if this approach works for you, or if you need any further assistance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. I put my chart and tablix inside the list and did group by month. It works, data for each month appears separately. Filtering is not working for me. Without filtering, list group  works great. Thanks for the answer. Appreciated.